# How to store promise data into a value provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

Am trying to store a promise data into a value provider to access data later on. but when I console.log the variable its not changed. Here is my code:

```
function getUser(iden, usersOnline) {
  //return promise here
  var Users = $resource('/api/users', {}, {
    query: {
      method: 'get',
      isArray: true
    }
  });
  $scope.usersOnline = 'a';

  return Users.query({
      username: usersOnline
    }).$promise
    //other code as is
}

$scope.id = 'cpasgrave';
$scope.lol = getUser();
$scope.lol.then(function(user) {
  console.log(user[0]._id);
  usersOnline = user[0]._id;
  $scope.userss = user;
});
console.log(usersOnline);

var aa = $resource('/api/updateUser', {}, {
  query: {
    method: 'put',
    isArray: true
  }
});
```

usersOnline is myvalue provider. Here is how I declare it:

```
myApp.value('usersOnline', '');
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to store the promise itself, not the value that will be created in the future, and you need to `return` that promise and the caller needs to wait for it.

Comment: thank you for your comment can you provide code please

Comment: Simply move the line `console.log(usersOnline);` up by one line.

Comment: Ok i see that its changed why doesnt it stay that way

Comment: It does stay that way until you change it again? You still seem to be confused by [asynchronous callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/1048572).